# Is there an App Engine alternative for .NET? Free or very cheap plan required

Tags: .net, google-app-engine, hosting, appharbor

I'm looking for a way to host my .NET app and if it were a Java app, I would use Google App Engine without blinking an eye. Is there a similar alternative for .NET?

Two features that are of highest importance:

- It has to be **free or very cheap** (ruling out Azure which is too expensive even in the cheapest plan)
- It has to be **reliable and fast** (problem with many free .NET hostings)

I did look at AppHarbor but whenever I see "instances" I'm put off (I don't want to think in terms of renting instance time, I just want to host my code and not worry about "instances"). Also, they seem to be targeting audience wanting some kind of Continuous Integration environment which again I don't need / want.

Is there such hosting service for .NET apps?

Comment: Note that in the new GAE price list you are charged per instance as well - http://www.google.com/enterprise/cloud/appengine/pricing.html

Comment: Interesting, I don't know how they charged higher-traffic websites in the past but I hope that nothing changes for the basic hosting feature.

Comment: The new pricing is not yet in effect. In general free quotas will be lower. You can read more in comments here http://tech.slashdot.org/story/11/09/01/2120247/new-prices-for-google-apps-engine

Comment: please don't let slashdot comments be your main source of information.  At least read some of the threads in the app engine google group before making a decision.

Comment: Found this thread useful: http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/400577-continue-azure-offering-free-for-developers. Quote from the answer: "We're working on ways to provide free and low cost onramps for developers, and expect to make more announcements in 2011." Has anything like that been announced yet?

Comment: There is a good discussion on programmers stack exchange here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/64727/windows-azure-vs-amazon-ec2-vs-google-app-engine

Answer (score 1):

Most Platform-as-a-service vendors work on instances. That's one of the benefits over traditional hosting (since you can scale on demand)

I wouldn't rule out Azure completely. An extra small instance costs around £30 a month and the [Windows Azure Accelerator for Web Roles](http://waawebroles.codeplex.com/) allows you to run multiple web sites on one instance.

I've never used AppHarbour but considering they'll give you a single instance free, I'd say that was a cheap startup. They don't have any requirement that you use CI but I do believe you deploy using Git or Mercurial so the deployment experience isn't quite as "nice" as Azure (not that Azure's is perfect by any means).

Typically however, "fast, reliable and cheap" won't come together.

Comment: "Typically however, "fast, reliable and cheap" won't come together." That's why I'm spoiled by GAE :)